# Streaming deserialization of a large json (array of objs) Java InputStream

Tags: java, deserialization, inputstream, resttemplate

There is a REST service for getting array of objects in json.
The response is usually very large - +1Gb.
Right now I my code does the following:

1. reads the whole response body
2. deseriaizes the json as an array of objects
3. processes objects in the array;

This takes too long, and consumes a lot of memory.

Could you, please, give some ideas how to do this more efficiently in Java (springframework, RestTemplate)?
For example, read and deserialze objects from the InputStream one by one (or in chunks) ?

p.s. We can't do any changes on the server side :(

Comment: see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api

Comment: Is it possible to split this big response body into chunks? You could stream the array of json objects with web socket and process each of them independently (in spring you can use WebFlux)